# Relational algebra - How to get all cards not used in a purchase?

Tags: relational-algebra

Suppose you have two tables:

Purchase(cardID,itemID)

MembershipCard(cardID,clientID,companyName)

How can I get all cardID's which were not used in a purchase using relational algebra?

It seems like division to me but I'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take all MembershipCards and remove all the ones that are in Purchase:

> π<sub>cardID</sub>(MembershipCard) - π<sub>cardID</sub>(Purchase)